# CodeIgniter - MySQL Error 1064 (Update table1 inner join table2(...))

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is now 6am in the morning and i'm still struggling to execute a query with the CodeIgniter PHP framewok. Hope you guys can help me

Code:

```
$query='
UPDATE `STUDY_LIST_AUX`
INNER JOIN `study_report` 
ON `STUDY_LIST_AUX.study_iuid`=`study_report.study_iuid`
SET `STUDY_LIST_AUX.report_date`=DATE_FORMAT(`study_report.report_date`,\'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s\'), `STUDY_LIST_AUX.report_status` = `study_report.report_status`
';

if ($this->db->query($query))
{
        echo "True!<br><br>";
}
else
{
        echo "False<br><br>";
};
```

Error:

> **A Database Error Occurred**
>
> *Error Number: 1064*
>
> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `STUDY_LIST_AUX` INNER JOIN `study_report` ON `STUDY_LIST_AUX.study_iu' at line 22*

I've tried everything, backticks, normal ticks, quote marks, but the error persists. On phpmyadmin the query run successfully.

Any suggestions or ideas will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: Have you tried without backticks in `ON` condition?

Comment: if U mean this ->`ON` - it didn't worked. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: I meant `ON STUDY_LIST_AUX.study_iuid = study_report.study_iuid`. Since your field names and table names seems OK, I guess no use of backticks, it just reduce the readability.

Comment: I've tried that option before , but nothing... :(

Comment: Hi, is this your exact query in your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your `query` code using this below Active Record code

```
$data = array('s.report_date' => 'DATE_FORMAT(`study_report.report_date`,\'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s\')','s.report_status' => 'sr.report_status');
$this->db->update('STUDY_LIST_AUX s JOIN study_report sr on s.study_iuid = sr.study_iuid',$data);
```

This'll help you...

Comment: Thanks, your answer didn't solve my problem, but it help me out fixing the syntax., but now I'm with another issue that I've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29997668/4853149

Answer (score 0):

try this. use double quote so you don't have to worry the quote inside

```
$query="UPDATE STUDY_LIST_AUX
INNER JOIN study_report 
ON STUDY_LIST_AUX.study_iuid = study_report.study_iuid
SET STUDY_LIST_AUX.report_date = 
DATE_FORMAT(study_report.report_date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'), 
STUDY_LIST_AUX.report_status = study_report.report_status";
```

Comment: No luck!! Still the same. Thanks

Comment: This answer should work. And if you are using codeigniter, why don't you use db->update()

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issue in the query ex:

```
 `STUDY_LIST_AUX.study_iuid`
```

If you are using backticks then it should be as

```
`STUDY_LIST_AUX`.`study_iuid`
```

The correct query should be

```
$query = "
update `STUDY_LIST_AUX` sla
join `study_report`  sr on sr.study_iuid = sla.study_iuid
set 
sla.report_date = date_format(sr.report_date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'),
sla.report_status = sr.report_status
";
```