# CodeIgniter - Error Number: 1146 (Table doesn't exist after execute a "CREATE TABLE" command)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've posted yesterday an issue with an mySQL update syntax on CodeIgniter in here:
[CodeIgniter - MySQL Error 1064 (Update table1 inner join table2(...))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29981882/4853149)

But now after I solved that problem, another one come up. Now the update query doesn't know the new created table. But if I change to a select statement, it works smoothly.

For that reason I've decided to post the full script.

**Code:**

```
<?php



$this->load->database();

$query_tbaux='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STUDY_LIST_AUX AS (

SELECT DISTINCT p.pat_id, p.pat_custom1 age, p.pat_name, 
p.pat_sex, s.study_iuid, p.pat_birthdate, s.accession_no, 
s.study_datetime date_s, s.study_desc, s.mods_in_study, s.pk, 
c.institution, s.study_block, s.study_urgent, 
\'0000-00-00 00:00:00\' AS \'report_date\', \'{null}\' AS \'report_status\',
s.study_tipo, 
s.study_src, 
s.study_consulta
FROM study s
INNER JOIN patient p ON s.patient_fk = p.pk
INNER JOIN series c ON c.study_fk = s.pk
INNER JOIN rel_users_hosp u ON u.hosp_id = c.institution
WHERE s.study_datetime >= \'2015-04-26 00:00:00\'
AND s.study_datetime <= \'2015-04-30 23:59:59\'
AND s.study_iuid IS NOT NULL
AND u.user_id =  \'admin\'

)';

if ($this->db->query($query_tbaux))
    {
        echo "Q True!<br><br>";
        $data = array(
               'STUDY_LIST_AUX.report_date' => "DATE_FORMAT(study_report.report_date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')",
               'STUDY_LIST_AUX.report_status' => 'study_report.report_status',
            );

        $this->db->update('STUDY_LIST_AUX, study_report', $data, array('STUDY_LIST_AUX.study_iuid'=>'study_report.study_iuid'));
    }
    else
        {
            echo "Q False<br><br>";
        };


?>
```

**Display/Error:**

> Q True!
>
> **A Database Error Occurred**
>
> *Error Number: 1146*
>
> *Table 'pacsdb.STUDY_LIST_AUX,' doesn't exist*
>
> *UPDATE `STUDY_LIST_AUX,` `study_report` SET*
>   *`STUDY_LIST_AUX`.`report_date` =*
>   *'DATE_FORMAT(study_report.report_date,\'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s\')',*
>   *`STUDY_LIST_AUX`.`report_status` = 'study_report.report_status' WHERE*
>   *`STUDY_LIST_AUX`.`study_iuid` = 'study_report.study_iuid'*

I've checked phpmyadmin after refresh the page and the table really exists and it contains the data from the select statement.Can you please tell me what mistake I did?

Comment: `update` function's first parameter should be a table name.  `'STUDY_LIST_AUX, study_report` is this your table name? should be `'STUDY_LIST_AUX'`

Answer (score 2):

This may cause you real problem.Remove **,study_report**
after your table name.Try it

```
$this->db-
>update('STUDY_LIST_AUX', 
$data, 
 array('STUDY_LIST_AUX.study_iuid'=>
'study_report.study_iuid'));
```

Comment: Now there is errors, but the update doesn't "update" nothing. I do want to have a sub query with an update "from another table" where table1.id=table2.id

Answer (score 0):

Pay closer attention.

> Table 'pacsdb.STUDY_LIST_AUX,'

See that comma at the end? That should not be there. The error message is right.

Comment: This should be comment not as answer.

Comment: Because it should be closed as a typo

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: Why? This identifies the problem with the query. So I didn't give a detailed step-by-step account of how to fix the query, but that's a personal choice. This is still an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are far experience than me.I think you better know than me how an answer should be.You just commented that OP made an mistake.May be he don't know it is his mistake. So it would be more helpful for him to explain why that is a mistake.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: I know from that experience that sometimes it is more helpful to let the OP make the final deductive leap on his or her own. In this case, is it not obvious that a table name does not include a trailing comma? The OP needs to learn that this is obvious so that he or she spots the problem themselves next time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was more simple than it looks.

```
$query_update = "UPDATE STUDY_LIST_AUX
        INNER JOIN study_report
        SET STUDY_LIST_AUX.report_date = DATE_FORMAT(study_report.report_date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'), STUDY_LIST_AUX.report_status = study_report.report_status
        WHERE STUDY_LIST_AUX.study_iuid = study_report.study_iuid";


$this->db->query($query_update);
```

It seems to be a issue with the CodeIgnigter Framework on the update integrated function ($this->db->update(...)). It doesn't work with sub queries, and the best solution goes for using the normal query execution function ($this->db->update($query))

Anyway, thanks for the help ;) All your answers were very helpful in a way to get to this solution.